# I am getting an error with the elif statement on line 34. It says invalid syntax. I tried changing the indents and the elif statement to if else

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, indentation, keyword

```
class book:
    def __init__(self,aut, pub, p, cp=0):
        self.author=aut
        self.publisher=pub
        self.price=p
        self.copies=cp
    def get_author(self):
        return self._author
    def set_author(self, aut):
        self._author=aut
        return
    author=property(get_author, set_author)
    def get_publisher(self):
        return self._publisher
    def set_publisher(self, pub):
        self._publisher=pub
        return
    publisher=property(get_publisher, set_publisher)
    def get_price(self):
        return self._price
    def set_price(self,p):
        self._price=p
        return
    price=property(get_price, set_price)
    def get_copies(self):
        return self._copies
    def set_copies(self,cp):
        self._copies=cp
        return
    copies=property(get_copies, set_copies) 
    def get_royalty(self):
        if self.copies<=500:
            self._royalty=self.copies*self.price*10/100
    elif:
         self.copies<=1000:
         self._royalty=500*self.price*10/100+ \
        (self.copies-500)*self.price*12.5/100
    else:
        self._royalty=500*self.price*10/100 + \
        500*self.price*12.5/100 + \
        (self.copies-1000)*self.price*15/100
        return self._royalty
class ebook(book):
    def __init__(self, aut, pub, p, cp=0, form=None):
    super().__init__(aut,pub,p,cp)
    self.format=form
    def get_format(self):
        return self._format
    def set_format(self, form):
        self._format=form
        return
    format=property(get_format, set_format)
    def get_royalty(self):
        ryl=super().get_royalty() 
        ryl=ryl-ryl*12/100
        self._royalty=ryl
        return self._royalty
 
if __name__== "__main__":
    print ('print book example')
    b1=book('aa','ss',100,600)
    print ("Royalty earned : ", b1.get_royalty())
    print ('ebook example')
    e1=ebook('aa','ss',100, 3, 'PDF')
    print ('Royalty earned' , e1.get_royalty())
```

I am getting an error with the elif statement on line 34. It says invalid syntax. I tried changing the indents and changing the elif statement to if else. I tried changing the indents of the def and return statements along with the elif statement, but there was no improvement. I also tried to merge the blocks of code, but that didn't help. What should I do to run the code error free?

Comment: Which line is line 34?

Comment: Check the indentation of the `elif` and `else` block in `get_royalty`, and the indentation of `ebook. __init__`. Note that `elif:` on its own is not valid syntax; you're missing a boolean condition there.

Comment: it should be like `elif self.copies<=1000` i.e add condition on else if.

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: are you familiar with `@decorators`? because I think they would help you tidy up the code. Other stuff to, like how are you even capable of reading this continuous block of code? you should learn to format it by adding a blank line here and there and two blank lines between classes  and functions

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the indentations of your code, and now the syntax error is gone, and everything is working as expected:

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, aut, pub, p, cp=0):
        self._author = aut
        self._publisher = pub
        self._price = p
        self._copies = cp

    def get_author(self):
        return self._author

    def set_author(self, aut):
        self._author = aut

    author = property(get_author, set_author)

    def get_publisher(self):
        return self._publisher

    def set_publisher(self, pub):
        self._publisher = pub

    publisher = property(get_publisher, set_publisher)

    def get_price(self):
        return self._price

    def set_price(self, p):
        self._price = p

    price = property(get_price, set_price)

    def get_copies(self):
        return self._copies

    def set_copies(self, cp):
        self._copies = cp

    copies = property(get_copies, set_copies)

    def get_royalty(self):
        if self._copies <= 500:
            self._royalty = self._copies * self._price * 10 / 100

        elif self._copies <= 1000:
            self._royalty = 500 * self._price * 10 / 100 + \
                    (self._copies - 500) * self._price * 12.5 / 100

        else:
            self._royalty = 500 * self._price * 10 / 100 + \
                500 * self._price * 12.5 / 100 + \
                (self._copies - 1000) * self._price * 15 / 100
        return self._royalty


class Ebook(Book):

    def __init__(self, aut, pub, p, cp=0, form=None):
        super().__init__(aut, pub, p, cp)
        self._format = form

    def get_format(self):
        return self._format

    def set_format(self, form):
        self._format = form

    format = property(get_format, set_format)

    def get_royalty(self):
        ryl = super().get_royalty()
        ryl = ryl - ryl * 12 / 100
        self._royalty = ryl
        return self._royalty


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('print book example')
    b1 = Book('aa', 'ss', 100, 600)
    print("Royalty earned : ", b1.get_royalty())
    print('ebook example')
    e1 = Ebook('aa', 'ss', 100, 3, 'PDF')
    print('Royalty earned', e1.get_royalty())
```